# Unhandled exception type ParseException with class object

Tags: java, json, unhandled-exception

The following error occurs on *RowsJ.getRows();* : **Unhandled exception type ParseException**.

```java
       public class Board 
       {
         ReadJson r = new ReadJson();
         long rows = r.getRows();
       {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       { 
         System.out.println(rows);
       }
       }
```

The method *getRows()* returns a long number from a JSON file.

Comment: So what exactly is your issue, do you want to handle the exception  here or just throw it and the main method would handle it ?

Comment: @Osama.070032  problem is i can't run the program without throwing the exceptions in the class,but when i do throw them(example: *public class Board throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException*) a lot of other syntax problems occur.

Comment: What is stopping you from handling the exception?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson as far as I know you cant throw exceptions for the whole class and this is I an object i need to use in different methods throughout the class.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "the whole class", are you talking about declarations at the top/root level like instance variables?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson yep exactly.

Comment: Then what about moving the assignment to a constructor or even better a factory method and have a `try/catch` inside of it?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Ok thank you for recommending try/catch.

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.